# How to implement playwright to keep browser pages open and not closed

Tags: python-3.x, playwright

I want the page to remain open, after executing the code below, so that I can perform some manual operations:

```
br = playwright.sync_api.sync_playwright().start().chromium.launch()
br.new_page().goto("xxxx") # Keep browser page open
```